# Graphing Template for y= with asymptote

Tags: pgfplots, windows, graphs

So I want to draw the graph

> y=(3^(x))+(-1)
>
> y=(3^(-x))+3

With label and thin grid

Showing the asymptotes clearly. **CLEARLY**

---

*I had tried the following*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  clip=false,
  ymin=0,
  xticklabels=\empty,
  yticklabels=\empty,
  legend pos=north west
]
\addplot+[mark=none,samples=200,unbounded coords=jump] {(3^(x))+(-1)};
\legend{$y=\sqrt{x}$}
\draw[fill] (axis cs:4,0) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[below right] {$(4,0)$};
\draw[fill] (axis cs:{4.5,sqrt(4.5)}) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[above left] {$(x,y)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

but failed to generate the +(-1) part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like ...

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            legend pos=north west,
            axis lines=middle,
            xmax=5,
            ymin=-2,
            ymax=10,
%            xticklabels=\empty,
%            yticklabels=\empty,
            % add some extra ticks with a different style to show the asymptotes
            extra y ticks={-1,3},
            extra y tick style={
                grid=major,
            },
%            % if you don't need the numbers ...
%            extra y tick labels={},
            no markers,
            samples=200,
        ]
            \addplot {(3^(x))+(-1)};
            \addplot {(3^(-x))+3};

%            % alternatively add some more constant plots where you choose
%            % a custom style for each asymptote
%            \addplot [blue!50,samples=2,forget plot] {-1};
%            \addplot [red!50,samples=2,forget plot] {3};

            \legend{
                $3^x - 1$,
                $3^{-x} + 3$,
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]